# Use LINQ-Like Expression in Angular

Tags: c#, angular

I want to filter data that coming from Web API (Back-end) to show some specific and filtered data to me. i have defined a service to get all the data from API

```
getAll()
  {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl)
  }
```

And in the component i have written

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAll().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('Result - ', data);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<EntryElement>(data as EntryElement[])
    });
  }
```

I would like to know is there any Linq like WHERE method to apply it on the `getAll()` service and filter the data?

Comment: How about using the `filter` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @jcruz I'm kinda new to angular. can show me how?

Comment: Basically, you can apply this to any array like this for example: `data.filter(item => item.Field == true)` If you can include sample data I can provide you with a better example.

Comment: @jcruz that's true but i actually don't where to apply filter method. for instance i cannot place it after getAll() like this.service.getAll().filter().subscribe(....)

Comment: That's why I used the example using your `data` parameter. Example: `let filteredData =  data.filter(item => item.Field == true)`

Comment: @jcruz now i get property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object' and i know we can only apply it on arrays

Comment: Again, sample data would be helpful. I don't know what `GetAll` actually returns.

Comment: @jcruz returns a list of entries. and entries include of (Id: number ,Description: string; IsExpense: boolean; Value: number; User: string;)

Comment: @jcruz Thanks a lot. i finally found the solution by defining data as (data : Array<any>)